# Scrolling combined with physics moves my sprite out of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm implementing a side scrolling game with SpriteKit:

As long as my sprite stays in the middle of the screen, I'm moving the sprite

[image]

When the sprite reaches the left or the right part of the screen, I'm moving the level instead of my sprite:

[image]

This works quite well, unless my sprite collides with another object. In that case the level (triggered by my code) and the sprite (triggered by the physics engine) are moved and the sprite moves outside the screen:

[image]

I tried to stop the impulse which is applied from the physics engine. This hasn't worked.

Any idea how to handle this?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: see the scrolling/camera follows node example in the spritekit programming guide, that keeps physics in sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose by "moving the level" you mean moving the background view.

Why don't you just have an area in which your sprite moves that is the same size as your background? You can scroll to keep the sprite visible without disturbing the logic of physics and other manipulation of the movement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My images are misleading. It's not the background. The problem is that I have a level which is bigger than the screen. After a collision the sprite moves faster to the right, as my level is scrolling in.

Comment: So you probably need to adjust the scroll speed to accommodate that. That is sort of similar to what I meant in the answer.

Comment: Right. I've tried that. The problem was, that I could not detect the speed of the sprite. Do you now, how to get the velocity caused by the collision? Thanks

Comment: Well, you always have the `position` property of your node.

Comment: Yes. I'll try that. I think now I'm on the right track. :-). Just have no time to fix it today. Thanks for your help.